# Error in Correspondence Analysis in R

Tags: r, correspondence-analysis

I used the function CA : CA(data[ ,2:5])

I got that graphic:

I have a contingency table with five columns: one qualitative data, and four quantitative data.
But instead of the numbers I'd like to get the label of my first column.
If I type `CA(data[ ,1:5])` R anwers me that the first column is qualitative and not quantitative and there is a compilation error, 
so would you know how to display the label of the first column without getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

Set the rownames of your dataset to match the first column.

```
rownames(data) <- data[,1]
plot(ca(data[,2:5]))
```